# mongoDb - How do I delete an object from a nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, findoneandupdate

```
    "ProductCategory": [
        {
          "_id": "6246e0d09b16cf549256ed75",
          "name": "Arduino Boards",
          "desc": "this is for demo purpose",
          "date": "2022-03-31T18:30:00.000Z",
          "products": [
            {
              "name": "Arduino Uno R3 CH340G",
              "imgUrl": "",
              "price": "799",
              "desc": "",
              "_id": "6246e1fb9b16cf549256ed77"
            },
            {
              "name": "Arduino Nano V3.0 ATMEGA 328P (with USB Cable)",
              "imgUrl": "",
              "price": "599",
              "desc": "",
              "_id": "6246e3049b16cf549256ed79"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": "6246e32d9b16cf549256ed7d",
          "name": "Sensors",
          "desc": "this is for demo purpose",
          "date": "2022-03-31T18:30:00.000Z",
          "products": [
            {
              "name": "PU6050 Gyroscope Sensor",
              "imgUrl": "",
              "price": "129",
              "desc": "",
              "_id": "6246e3d29b16cf549256ed7f"
            },
            {
              "name": "CCS811 Carbon Monoxide Gas Sensor",
              "imgUrl": "",
              "price": "1799",
              "desc": "",
              "_id": "6246e3d29b16cf549234ea3r"
            }
          ]
        }
```

This is a data in mongoDB with the collection named as  **ProductCategory**.
I want to find the product with **_id "6246e3049b16cf549256ed79"** which is **"Arduino Nano V3.0 ATMEGA 328P (with USB Cable)"**. How can I **find** it and also **delete** it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete from a nested array, you can use pipeline update and `$filter` for this:

```
db.ProductCategory.update({
  "products._id": idToDelete
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      products: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$products",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$ne: ["$$item._id", idToDelete]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This will filter the `products` array to contain only items that their id is not `idToDelete`.

You can see it works on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/srgCtb03lFT)

In order to just find the document, you can use:

```
db.ProductCategory.find({"products._id": idToDelete})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.categories.deleteOne( {"_id": ObjectId("6246e3049b16cf549256ed79")});
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/remove-documents/

Comment: It is not able to find the product or delete the product.

Comment: Read the documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/remove-documents/ you can delete documents by id from your collection

Comment: Yes, but we can use this syntax for those which we can find at very outside of the document. The one which I want to find and delete is the nested one. Means there is a main object named "Arduino Board". We can find and delete it by this method. But inside it there is objects named "products" which is an array of objects. So to delete inside the products array is not possible by this syntax.